# Contexto y parámetros en metodos C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy desarrollando una applicacion MVC en C# y me encuentro con que TODOS los métodos de mis clases deben recibir el contexto e "identificador de empresa" porque son necesarios para acceder a mi modelo de datos.
Existe alguna manera de instanciarlo y tenerlo accesible desde todos lados y asi no enviarlo como parámetro en todos mis métodos?

Con esta funcion obtengo mi contexto

```
public DbContext GetContext(Empresa pEmpresa, bool pProxyCreationEnabled, bool pLazyLoadingEnabled)
{
    DbContext result;
    result = GetContext(pEmpresa);
    result.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = pProxyCreationEnabled;
    result.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = pLazyLoadingEnabled;
    result.Database.CommandTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;
    return result;
}
```

Y luego tengo que pasarlo SIEMPRE como parametro a TODOS los métodos:

```
public Cliente GetCliente (DbContext pContext, long pIdEmpresa, string pCliente)
```

`pContext` es mi contexto Entity Framework, `pIdEmpresa` es la BD a la que estoy accediendo.

Comment: Hola Leonardo, bivenido al sitio! Si eres Nuevo en ASP.net MVC, te recomiendo ver el workshop que hice en vivo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Por otro lado te recomiendo visitar: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que te familiarices con el sitio. Estás usando multiples bases de datos? Por qué razón tienes que pasar los contextos como parámetros? Échale una lectura a: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1155/aspnet-mvc-repository-pattern-perform-database-operations y https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: de la misma manera, revisa:  https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/285/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-and-services-in-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que lo guardes como variable de session

te dejo el link para saber mas al respecto.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/03sekbw5(v=vs.100).aspx